# Yii2 dynamic form wbraganca

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, dynamicform

I am using wbraganca dynamic form in yii2-advanced app. I'm referring to - [wbraganca dynamic form - github](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform) as a tutorial; but I do not understand what the 'addresses' field is they are using in their customerController. I'm sharing it's screenshot here - [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWg58.png). please refer the respective link & screenshot & help me to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The 'addresses' field is a relation in the Customer model with the Address model. The Customer model contains a relation:

```
class Customer extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord 
{
    ....
    public function getAddresses() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Address::className(), ['customer_id'=>'id']);
    }
}
```

The number of records in the Address model changes with the help of this widget

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for your reply I didn't get any method started with get--  in my project actually create method working fine in but when I was trying to update I am getting error. I have added code and screen in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946322/undefined-variable-yii2?noredirect=1#comment57627368_34946322 this link

Comment: Replied in that topic. I hope this helps.