# Undefined variable: yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions, yii-components

[image] Getting error when I am trying to create dynamic form in using yii2-dynamicform. at the time of create method it is working fine but at the time of update showing the error. I have two tables one is 
1.vendors & 
2.vendors_more_categories

Relation is 1-* between vendors & vendors_more_categories I just refereed https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform this link.

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;
namespace backend\controllers;
use Yii;
use app\models\Vendors;
use app\models\VendorsSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use app\models\VendorsMoreCategories;
use backend\models\Model;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
/**
 * VendorsController implements the CRUD actions for Vendors model.
 */
class VendorsController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['index','create', 'update', 'delete'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['index','create', 'update', 'delete'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Vendors models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new VendorsSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Vendors model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Vendors model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Vendors();
        $modelsVendorsMoreCategories = [new VendorsMoreCategories];
        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){        

            $modelsVendorsMoreCategories = Model::createMultiple(VendorsMoreCategories::classname());
            Model::loadMultiple($modelsVendorsMoreCategories, Yii::$app->request->post());


            // validate all models
            $valid = $model->validate();
            $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsVendorsMoreCategories) && $valid;

            if ($valid) {
                $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
                try {
                    if ($flag = $model->save(false)) {
                        foreach ($modelsVendorsMoreCategories as $modelVendorsMoreCategories) {
                            $modelVendorsMoreCategories->vmc_ven_id = $model->ven_id;
                            if (! ($flag = $modelVendorsMoreCategories->save(false))) {
                                $transaction->rollBack();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($flag) {
                        $transaction->commit();

                        $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
                        $save_file = '';
                        if($model->file){
                            $imagename = Vendors::find()->orderBy('ven_id DESC')->one();
                            $imagename=$imagename->ven_id+1;
                            $imagepath = 'images/imgvendors/'; // Create folder under web/uploads/logo
                            $model->ven_business_logo = $imagepath.$imagename.'.'.$model->file->extension;
                            $save_file = 1;
                        }
                        if ($model->save(false)) {
                            if($save_file){
                                $model->file->saveAs($model->ven_business_logo);
                            }
                            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ven_id]);
                        }                        
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }
            }            
        }else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'modelsVendorsMoreCategories' => (empty($modelsVendorsMoreCategories)) ? [new VendorsMoreCategories] : $modelsVendorsMoreCategories
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Vendors model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        //print_r($model->attributes);

        $modelsVendorsMoreCategories = $model->ven_id;   

        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){          
            $oldIDs = ArrayHelper::map($modelsVendorsMoreCategories, 'id', 'id');
            $modelsVendorsMoreCategories = Model::createMultiple(VendorsMoreCategories::classname(), $modelsVendorsMoreCategories);
            Model::loadMultiple($modelsVendorsMoreCategories, Yii::$app->request->post());
            $deletedIDs = array_diff($oldIDs, array_filter(ArrayHelper::map($modelsVendorsMoreCategories, 'id', 'id')));

            // validate all models
            $valid = $model->validate();
            $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsVendorsMoreCategories) && $valid;

            if ($valid) {
                $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
                try {
                    if ($flag = $model->save(false)) {
                        if (! empty($deletedIDs)) {
                            Address::deleteAll(['id' => $deletedIDs]);
                        }
                        foreach ($modelsVendorsMoreCategories as $modelVendorsMoreCategories) {
                            $modelVendorsMoreCategories->vmc_ven_id = $model->ven_id;
                            if (! ($flag = $modelVendorsMoreCategories->save(false))) {
                                $transaction->rollBack();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($flag) {
                        $transaction->commit();
                        $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
                        $save_file = '';
                        if($model->file){
                            $imagepath = 'images/imgvendors/'; // Create folder under web/uploads/logo
                            $model->ven_business_logo = $imagepath.$model->ven_id.'.'.$model->file->extension;
                            $save_file = 1;
                        }

                        if ($model->save(false)) {
                            if($save_file){
                                $model->file->saveAs($model->ven_business_logo);
                            }
                            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ven_id]);
                        }                        

                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }
            }

        }else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
                'modelsVendorsMoreCategories' => (empty($modelsVendorsMoreCategories)) ? [new VendorsMoreCategories] : $modelsVendorsMoreCategories
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Vendors model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Vendors model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Vendors the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Vendors::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
    //Function used for deleting the images
    public function actionDeleteimg($id, $field)
    {

        $img = $this->findModel($id)->$field;
        if($img){
            if (!unlink($img)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        $img = $this->findModel($id);
        $img->$field = NULL;
        $img->update();

        return $this->redirect(['update', 'id' => $id]);
    }
    //Function used for getting more sub categories for vendor
    public function actionGetSubCategories()
    {
        $mbcid=$_GET['ven_main_category_id'];
        $sbcid=$_GET['ven_sub_category_id'];
        echo $mbcid;
    }
    public function actionLists($id)
    {
        $countVendors = Vendors::find()->where(['ven_contact_person_id' => $id])->count();
        $vendors = Vendors::find()->where(['ven_contact_person_id' => $id])->all();
        if ($countVendors > 0) {
            foreach ($vendors as $vendor) {
                echo "<option value='" . $vendor->ven_id . "'>" . $vendor->ven_company_name . "</option>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<option></option>";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: name `modelsVendorsMoreCategories` is have some typo error. check with respective action.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply can you can you check my code, I didn't get your answer.

Comment: Do You pass `$modelsVendorsMoreCategories` variable when rendering _form file?

Comment: I am rendering it as - return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
                'modelsVendorsMoreCategories' => (empty($modelsVendorsMoreCategories)) ? [new VendorsMoreCategories] : $modelsVendorsMoreCategories
            ]);

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByAsJNXfro3UVVNZTkFvbGR6Yms/view?usp=sharing check from this link

Comment: show your relations and model code. As scaisEdge mentioned this line is wrong ` $modelsVendorsMoreCategories = $model->ven_id;` this should be filled with your relation not with the ven_id integer value.

Comment: How can I define relation in update method?

Answer (score 0):

You accessing modelsVendorsMoreCategories[0]  (as an element of an array )

```
  'model'=> $modelsVendorsMoreCategories[0],
```

in your DinamicForm widget but when you  update  the model  you pass    as $modelsVendorsMoreCategories this value

```
   $modelsVendorsMoreCategories = $model->ven_id;
```

(don't seems an array, you must be sure this object contain an array with a proper element in 0 index))

```
'modelsVendorsMoreCategories' => (empty($modelsVendorsMoreCategories)) ? 
       [new VendorsMoreCategories] : $modelsVendorsMoreCategories
        ]);
```

Comment: I have update an answer.. seems you don'have a proper array elemeny in array.

Comment: I am referring https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform this tutorial they taken $modelCustomer = $this->findModel($id);
        $modelsAddress = $modelCustomer->addresses; like this but where is 'addresses' defined?

Comment: I don't know braganza and i don't know what are you trying to do but i suggest you of check if this content is coherent with your need.. try a var_dump( $modelsVendorsMoreCategories) before render a check the content.

Answer (score 0):

$modelsVendorsMoreCategories should contain the VendorsMoreCategories model in actionUpdate method. In this code ($modelsVendorsMoreCategories = $model->ven_id) $modelsVendorsMoreCategories contains $model->ven_id. It is an integer value, not the VendorsMoreCategories object.

The Vendors model should contain a relation on the VendorsMoreCategories model:

```
class Vendors extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord 
{
    ....
    public function getVendorsMoreCategories() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(VendorsMoreCategories::className(), 'vendor_id'=>'id']);
    }
}
```

And then, you should use that relation in your actionUpdate method:

```
$model = $this->findModel($id);

$modelsVendorsMoreCategories = $model->vendorsMoreCategories;
if(!$modelsVendorsMoreCategories) {
    $modelsVendorsMoreCategories = [new VendorsMoreCategories];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your actionUpdate you have:

```
$modelsVendorsMoreCategories = $model->ven_id;
```

But you should have:

```
$modelsVendorsMoreCategories = $model->nameOfMyRelation;
```

To get what's the real name, go in your $model, and look for something like:

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getNameOfMyRelation()
{
    return $this->hasMany(VendorsMoreCategories::className(), ['ven_id' => 'id']);
}
```

If you don't have any function making the relation of this two tables, write one. If you having trouble doing that, you can always use the [gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html)'s model generator and check the Vendors model (you dont need to replace it, just preview the code).

Answer (score 0):

> Check your create.php file in view folder, pass required variable on
>   _form.php file from here as:-

```
 <?= $this->render('_form', [
    'model' => $model,
    'modelsAddress' => $modelsAddress,
]) ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

**Check Your create file in view folder:**

**Controller:**
      Controller pass the parameter into create.php

```
 return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'modelsVendorsMoreCategories' => (empty($modelsVendorsMoreCategories)) ? [new VendorsMoreCategories] : $modelsVendorsMoreCategories
        ]);
```

**View:create.php**

If You miss the parameter: **'modelsVendorsMoreCategories' =>$modelsVendorsMoreCategories**.
   It shows the Undefined variable error in _form.php page.

```
<?= $this->render('_form', [
            'model' => $model,
            'modelsVendorsMoreCategories' =>$modelsVendorsMoreCategories
 ])?>
```

**View:_form.php**

```
$modelsVendorsMoreCategories[0];
```

the paramater not passing before now it passing.

Comment: This answers lack of explanation and seems strangly similar than @vinod answers!

Comment: Controller first pass the **model and modelsVendorsMoreCategories** into create.php page and render into _form.php page.

Comment: So check the create.php page in view folder.

Comment: You don't get it, you need to edit your answer to provide something of quality, you used vinod answer without any new input so this is not a correct answer. Don't try to gain reputation like this, new users are monitored.